# jQuery - when clicking on elements too fast animations get buggy

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-ui

I've been working on this jQuery effect heres the fiddle:
**http://jsfiddle.net/abtPH/26/**

Everything's pretty good so far, however when I click on the elements too fast it seems to get buggy and get weird behavior. If you take your time and click on the elements it works fine.

I've tried using `:animate`

stuff to make sure the animation ends before the user can click on the next one. I do not like this approach though because from a end user it seems like the effects are laggy. I want the user to be able to click on the elements fast and have the desired effect.

Here's my jQuery so far:

```
$('li').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var active = $(this).siblings('.active');
    var posTop = ($(this).position()).top;
    if (active.length > 0) {
        var activeTop = (active.position()).top;
        if (activeTop == posTop) {
            $(this).find('.outer').fadeIn('medium', function () {
                active.toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').fadeOut('medium');
            });

        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.active').toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').slideToggle();
            $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
        }
    } else {
        $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
});
$('.outer').on('click', function (e) {
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [.finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) complete all the queued animation before beginning a new one

```
$('li').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var active = $(this).siblings('.active');
    var posTop = ($(this).position()).top;
    if (active.length > 0) {
        var activeTop = (active.position()).top;
        if (activeTop == posTop) {
            $(this).find('.outer').finish().fadeIn('medium', function(){ 
                active.finish().toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').finish().fadeOut('medium');
            });

        } else {
            $(this).siblings('.active').finish().toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').finish().slideToggle();
            $(this).find('.outer').finish().slideToggle();
        }
    } else {
        $(this).find('.outer').finish().slideToggle();
    }
    $(this).finish().toggleClass('active', 400);
});
$('.outer').on('click', function(e){
    return false;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/m5sN5/)

Comment: i;ve tried finish.() its still buggy though....if you click on the first row of boxes really fast and then go the the bottom you will see what i am talking about